# Powershell ConvertTo-SecureString not recognised if run script inline from cmd

Tags: powershell

When running from cmd.exe

```
powershell .\scripts\scriptname.ps1
```

Which has a line to convert plain text to secure string

```
[securestring]$secString = ConvertTo-SecureString $SampleString -AsPlainText -Force
```

I get error:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : The 'ConvertTo-SecureString' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'.
```

However if I open / run the script direct in powershell it runs fine?

If I try to import the module manually I get:

```
Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member AuditToString is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member AccessToString is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member Sddl is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member Access is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member Group is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member Owner is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member Path is already present.
```

Powershell version is

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      22621  963
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The symptom of your call to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, from `cmd.exe` (or a batch file) implies that you've launched `cmd.exe` *from [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)*.

In other words: the chain of calls is:

- PowerShell (Core) (`pwsh.exe`) -> `cmd.exe` -> Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`)

This ***indirect* call from PowerShell (Core) to Windows PowerShell is the problem**: It makes the latter use the former's definition of the `$env:PSModulePath` and therefore results in attempts to load - incompatible - PowerShell (Core) modules.

Such an indirect call bypasses the logic that is built into PowerShell (Core) when *directly* invoking `powershell.exe` (dynamic removal of PowerShell (Core)-specific entries from `$env:PSModulePath`) and therefore requires a **workaround**:

Per [GitHub issue #18530](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18530#issuecomment-1325691850), the solution is to **(temporarily) reset the `PSModulePath` environment variable**:

```bash
:: From cmd.exe (a batch file).
set "PSModulePath="
powershell .\scripts\scriptname.ps1
```

---

Note:

- As [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) points out, when a process-specific value for `PSModulePath` is defined, `powershell.exe` uses this value *as-is*, which is problematic: unless the value includes the standard locations, required modules may not be discoverable.
- By contrast, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI, is smarter about this: It automatically ensures the presence of all standard locations, even if a process-level value doesn't include them.
- The exact rules for how the effective `$env:PSModulePath` value is determined are complex; they are documented as part of the conceptual [`about_PSModulePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath#powershell-psmodulepath-construction) help topic.
- Note that even the default `$env:PSModulePath` values place the standard *current-user* module location first, making it possible to override standard cmdlets.

  - In both editions it is possible to place additional locations *first*:

    - implicitly, in Windows PowerShell, by defining a process-level value that determines the effective value *as-is*, as discussed.
    - explicitly, in PowerShell 7+, by *including* the current-user location in the process-level value, *at the end*.

Comment: He's really going pwsh -> cmd -> powershell. I guess powershell 5.1 doesn't set the psmodulepath if it's set already.  Doesn't sound very secure to me.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer above, I needed to do the following.  I was calling a PS 5 script from a PS 7 script and the called script contained `ConvertTo-SecureString`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-File $script", $Parm1, $Parm2 -Environment @{PSModulePath  = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\ShareGate\'} -Wait
```